# Существуют ли способы "заставить" перезаписывать значение переменной во всех поколениях дочерних классов в c#?

Tags: c#, наследование

Я пытаюсь сделать библиотеку, в которой у многих объектов будет возможность построения из стороннего файла данных динамически. Для того, чтобы упростить создание этих файлов данных, я решил добавить поддержку сокращений, реализовав это через класс **Alias**. Вот его примерный код:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Класс, описывающий возможные сокращения для указанного типа.
    /// </summary>
    public class Alias
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Массив со значениями сокращений, за которые отвечает этот экземпляр.
        /// </summary>
        public readonly string[] Aliases;
        /// <summary>
        /// Создаёт новый список допустимых сокращений для указанного типа.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="acceptableAliases"></param>
        public Alias(params string[] acceptableAliases)
        {
            Aliases = acceptableAliases;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Проверяет, является ли строка одним из указанных сокращений.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="test"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool Check(string test)
        {
            return Aliases.Any(x => x == test);
        }
}
```

Затем, в любой элемент, который должен иметь возможность построения с помощью этих сокращений, я добавляю статическое свойство, которое будет хранить эти сокращения:

```cs
    public class Message : TextBlock, ITemporary
    {
        protected new static Alias Aliases => new Alias("message", "msg");
```

И для каждого элемента я создаю новую переменную, которая перекрывает старую. Но я не думаю, что это удобно. Этих поколений много, и все элементы по цепочке наследуются от одного общего класса
**Существует ли способ сделать статическое свойство/поле только для чтения  в родительском классе так, чтобы в каждом потомке для любого поколения нужно было бы только выставить другое значение?

Либо, если существует другой, более удобный способ справиться с этой задачей, хотелось бы узнать его.**
У каждого элемента данная переменная должна быть уникальной, например у класса GroupBox один список допустимых значений один:

```cs
public class GroupBox : Control, IContainer<Control>
    {
        protected new static Alias Aliases => new Alias("groupbox", "group-box", "container", "group", "div");
```

У класса Menu, который от него наследуется, уже другой:

```cs
 public class Menu : GroupBox
    {
        protected new static Alias Aliases => new Alias("menu");
```

Comment: "И, как видно из кода, я создаю новую переменную в каждом поколении элементов." - что это, черт возьми, может значить? (Из кода ни черта не видно.)

Comment: Ну, например, у меня есть один исходный класс. У него свой набор алиасов. От него наследуется второй, у которого этот набор уже другой. У третьего, который наследуется от второго, этот набор тоже отличается. Нужно, чтобы у каждого класса были свои алиасы, при этом хочется, чтобы обозначались они одной переменной. Применяются они к типу, а не к экземплярам

Comment: `свойство ... только для чтения ... чтобы ... выставить другое значение` - у меня когнитивный диссонанс, эта фраза сама себе противоречит. Когда я залезаю в дебри и путаюсь - удаляю код и начинаю все сначала, от задачи. И я не понял, в чем именно ваша проблема. Оно не работает?

Comment: Кстати, как по-вашему этот механизм будет использоваться? Дополните вопрос.

Comment: Если есть возможность, сделайте класс `Alias` абстрактным с абстрактным свойством `Aliases`. Тогда все его наследники будут обязаны определить это свойство.

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать интерфейс `IAlias` со свойством `Aliases` и с дефолтной реализацией метода `Check`. По-моему, это будет выглядеть лучше, чем вариант со статическими членами. Но можно забыть переопределить реализацию в наследниках.

Comment: Чтобы не забыть сделать переопределение какого-либо члена в потомках, можно написать модульные тесты для этого. В тестах проходим по сборкам проекта, находим нужные типы и рефлексией ищем нужные методы/свойства. Естественно, билд-сервер должен быть настроен так, чтобы не пропускать в продакшн код с таким упавшим тестом. | Дальнейшее развитие этого свособа: написать анализатор Roslyn. Он делает те же самые проверки, но прямо в процессе написания кода. Сложно, но осуществимо.

Comment: Простите, что у меня не получается чётко объяснить, что я хочу, я ещё учусь программированию и у меня могут быть проблемы с формулировкой. @aepot, перекрытие переменной от родителя с помощью new работает, но это не принуждает к созданию нового значения в каждом новом классе. Если вдруг понадобится написать новый класс, который будет наследоваться от базового или его потомков, хотелось бы, чтобы появлялось предупреждение или ошибка, указывающая на то, что нужно указать другое значение

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, хорошая идея, можно будет попробовать

Comment: Вы проигнорировали мой последний вопрос. Как это используется? Дело в том, что оно в целом выглядит не очень хорошо. У меня есть идея, как переделать, но я представления не имею, как использовать то, что вы написали.

Comment: Есть условный xml-файл, в котором расписаны все эти элементы и их свойства. Для удобства создания xml-файла я решил сделать, чтобы вместо полного названия типа можно было указывать его псевдоним в теге. Массив всех псевдонимов как раз хранится в свойстве Aliases у каждого из этих элементов. Сначала я просто заполняю список этих сокращений в отдельном классе и затем создаю из него же, сканируя xml элементы и находя, как какому из них относится псевдоним

Comment: Только сейчас заметил ошибку, вместо protected должен быть другой модификатор доступа, а то нет возможности увидеть это свойство из других классов

Comment: Статические абстрактные методы/свойства пока не поддерживаются, но в недалёком будущем [будут](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4436).

Comment: @VladD, тогда подожду, пока появятся, до этого момента оставлю, как есть. Всем спасибо за помощь